# adding directory to Liberty profile classpath not working on linux while working on windows

Tags: linux, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am trying to add a directory containing properties files to Liberty profile classpath. And use the file from application. The files are getting added to classpath in windows platform but on linux it is giving file not found error.

Below is the server.xml contents for both platform for reference.

Windows;

`<library id="MySQL-Driver" name="MySQL-Driver">
    <folder dir="C:\Tool\sdm-config"/>
</library>
<webApplication contextRoot="abc-war" id="abc-war" location="abc-war.war" name="abc-war">
        <classloader privateLibraryRef="MySQL-Driver"/> 
</webApplication>`

Linux;

`<library id="MySQL-Driver" name="MySQL-Driver">
    <folder dir="/ashish/sdmconfig"/>
</library>
<webApplication contextRoot="abc-war" id="abc-war" location="abc-war.war" name="abc-war">
    <classloader privateLibraryRef="MySQL-Driver"/>
</webApplication>`

Code to load properties file;

```
public void load(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        java.net.URL url = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
        in = url.openStream();

        load(in);

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the error on logs is 
E GORCR9999E:              Default: failed to load 'EPASSConfig.properties' -- java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to load 'EPASSConfig.properties' -- java.lang.NullPointerException

Is there some different syntax for linux I am missing here?

Thanks in advance, please help here.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Did you check if that folder is accessible by the user that starts Liberty? The only thing comes to my mind is either access rights or case sensitivity.

Comment: Yes, server is started by root user and directory and all files have root root(Owner/Group) permission. The lrt says -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  574 Sep  4 19:07 EPASSConfig.properties

Comment: Could you please post actual error message?

Comment: Updated in question.

Comment: Please try to restart the server. I had similar error when server was not restarted after configuring library.

Comment: Restarting the server should not be necessary.  If that fixes the problem, please report the problem to IBM (IBM forum, PMR, etc.).

Comment: Pls, having the same issue here on windows and linux. Did you solve this issue? If so, how did you solve it?  Thanks